# Laravel - How to redirect with hash (#)

Tags: laravel

I have link :

```
example.com/register#register
```

If validation fails laravel redirects to :

```
example.com/register
```

with validation errors bit without hash url part. How I can redirect to full url with # ?

I know I can use:

```
Redirect::to(route('register') . '#credits')
```

But I want complete solution so and my :

```
return back();
```

will redirect with #.

Maybe I need to override some code ?

Comment: You basically have three options: 1) the one you write above, 2) using a URL::previous() call, and 3) adding the hash to your form action. For some more info, please see https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/laravel/redirect-back-with-an-anchor-tag

Answer (score 21):

You could create the URL first, using the route name.

```
$url = URL::route('route_name', ['#hash_tag']);

Redirect::to($url);
```

Or...

```
return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . "#hash_tag");
```

Comment: This solution worked like a charm! BTW, it's also possible to use a helper to achieve the same result: `redirect()->route('route_name', [ '#hash_tag' ])`. It's the same logic, just a different syntax.

Answer (score 17):

But if you want to get the proper URL where hash is the fragment part and not a parameter you should use:

```
redirect(route('route_name', ['some_param_for_route']). '#hash')
```

instead of:

```
redirect()->route('route_name', [ 'some_param_for_route', '#hash' ])
```

so to get:

```
http://example.com/some_param_for_route#hash
```

and not:

```
http://example.com/some_param_for_route?#hash
```

this way you can also chain it further like for instance:

```
redirect(route('route_name', ['some_param']). '#hash')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
```

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 5):

The best solution with Laravel 9.x

```php
return to_route('route.name')->withFragment('#comments');
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the best option as per my view and your requirement.

You should use

```
return back()->withFragment('#hashtag');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use helper:

```
redirect()->route('route_name', [ 'some_param_for_route', '#hash' ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to redirect with a hashtag or fragment

in the blade, form put the following input

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="{{Request::url()}}">
```

and get the URL and save it on the variable

```
$url = $request->url . '#comment_area';
```

at the end redirect to $url

```
return redirect($url)->with('success', 'message');
```

the best solution used the following code.

```
return redirect()->to(url()->previous())->withFragment('#comment_area')->with('success', 'message');
```

or

```
return redirect()->route('route.name')->withFragment('#comment_area');
```

:)