# How to pass value to url from controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a single page website where all the information are loaded in single page. All my website sections are divided by id. For example

```
<section id="banner">
</section>
<section id="aboutus">
</section>
```

Suppose when I load page, I want it to take me in about us section automatically.
I have tried by writing 127.0.0.1:8000/#aboutus in address bar manually and it worked. Now from controller I want to pass #aboutus in url.

How can i achieve that? In my controller

```
public function index()
{   
   return view('landingpage');
}
```

How to put `#abouts` in url from controller?

Comment: do you want to redirect to about us page when u click on about us ,or do you want to make about us the default page?

Comment: you are returning a view, if you want a new url, you will have to either redirect to that url, or change it in the frontend with javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: `#` is the `id` off html element attribute

Comment: @Hirumina In landing page there is aboutus section . I want to directly show to that page without scrolling

Comment: @STA yes. i have placed <section id="aboutus">. When i type #aboutus in url i get desired results but confused how can i do that from controller

Comment: This is done in the frontend, not the backend. The backend only prints out your page, in the frontend you can manipulate things like scrolling to an id

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply with anchor (`<a>`) tags within your view

```
<li>
    <a href="#aboutus">About Us</a>
<li/>
```

No javascript is required.

---

If you want to append the hash to the url on load, this answer may be of use

[Laravel - How to redirect with hash (#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355156/laravel-how-to-redirect-with-hash)