# redirect route with # laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I use "return  redirect()->route()" to routing but I have a tab named "#tab4" but cannot add this to url with redirect()->route. I want to show the same tab after submit but cannot set the url.when I use redirect()->back(), cannot see success message and page does not resresh. How to do that in laravel?

```php
sessionsuccess("asdfghj.");

return  redirect()->route('manage.customers.detail', ['account' => $this->account->id]);
```

the url I want: http://localhost:8000/manage/customers/detail/9#tab4

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - How to redirect with hash (#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355156/laravel-how-to-redirect-with-hash)

Answer (score 0):

web.php on route

```
Route::view('/#detail', 'manage.customers.detail/{account_id}')->name('detail');
```

on controller

```
return  redirect()->route("detail")->with("account_id"=>$this->account_id);
```

Try this.I believe working this

Comment: So you will create a different route for every tab? That might work, but it's not a good solution.

Comment: you can this foreach with use prefix but dont need this  manage.customers.detail just changing parameters value route is same but ıf you want use prefix route patch foreach

Comment: Or you can keep it simple and dynamic, and chain the tab to the outputted route. So you don't need to edit the route file for every new tab. Adding the tab links in the routes is not a good solution at all. Your route file will be a lot larger, it's harder to maintain.

Comment: I have no idea about this subject. Can you share an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
return redirect()->to(route('manage.customers.detail', ['account' => $this->account->id]).'#tab4');
```

Comment: Please explain your answer instead of just saying "try this".

Answer (score 0):

Store your current tab inside a session variable. after loading view, sessions can be used and retrieve your last tab

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your tab as a flash so whenever you submitted the tab can be active
in your controller method

```
Session::flash('tab', 'table_name');
```

and in your view you can work like this

```
Session::has('tab')? 'active' :''
```

for more details
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#flash-data

second way you can work link

return redirect()->route('manage.customers.detail', ['account' => $this->account->id, '#tab4']);